# Error on npm install: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp

Tags: node.js, windows, nativescript, npm-install

Below is the error log

```
Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Users\king\AppData\Local\Temp'
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:885:18)
    at sync (C:\Users\king\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:71:13)
    at sync (C:\Users\king\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:77:24)
    at sync (C:\Users\king\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
    at sync (C:\Users\king\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
    at sync (C:\Users\king\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
    at sync (C:\Users\king\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
    at sync (C:\Users\king\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
    at sync (C:\Users\king\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
    at sync (C:\Users\king\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
```

Comment: Seems to duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42678759/npm-error-on-every-command-eexist-file-already-exists-mkdir-c-users-user-ap

Comment: still not working.. i don't know what should i do

Answer (score 0):

delete npm and npm cache directories as well as also delete the configstore directory
It helped me hope it helps you