# "Error: EEXIST: file already exists" when running starter command for Remix.run

Tags: npm, npx, remix.run

I've never been really familiar with the `npx` command but from my understanding it's just a way of executing NPM packages, which is required in the [Getting started guide from Remix.run web framework](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/tutorials/blog).

It's really frustrating to just get stuck on the first step when I simply have to execute the `npx create-remix@latest` command. I get the following error:

```
Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Users\Ruben'
command not found: create-remix
```

Not sure what happens underlying but I don't know why it's trying to create a folder in the C drive when I execute this on `D:\Github\new-project`

NPM/NPX version: 6.14.6

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with your node/npm configuration rather then remix.run.

**.npmrc file at C:\Users\Ruben**

Do you have a .npmrc file? Maybe try and delete it as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63262906/6331985) details.

If you Google for "npx eexist file already exists", you will find several threads with the same issue and it seems to be a node/npm installation/configuration issue: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22825490/npm-wont-run-due-to-eexist-error/22825707#22825707), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42678759/npm-error-on-every-command-eexist-file-already-exists-mkdir-c-users-user-ap)